# if statements works wrong

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Here my `templates/deployment.yaml` snippet code:

```
volumes:
  - name: notebooks
  {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "sdfsdf"
  {{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
  {{- end -}}
  - name: logs
  {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "sdfsdfdsf"
  {{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
  {{- end -}}
  - name: conf
  {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"
  {{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
  {{- end -}}
```

Currently, I'm getting:

```
& helm template zeppelin ./
Error: YAML parse error on zeppelin/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 95: block sequence entries are not allowed in this context
```

It's getting me:

> block sequence entries are not allowed in this context

I've tried to clean a bit up the code:

```
  volumes:
    - name: notebooks
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: "sdfsdf"
    - name: logs
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: "sdfsdfdsf"
    - name: conf
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"
```

It's rendered coorectly.

What's wrong on `if` statements?

Answer (score 6):

You have some extra trims in your if/else statements that break the yaml structure.

Working example:

```
volumes:
  - name: notebooks
  {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "sdfsdf"
  {{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
  {{- end }}
  - name: logs
  {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "sdfsdfdsf"
  {{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
  {{- end }}
  - name: conf
  {{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: "sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"
  {{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
  {{- end }}
```

More info about [controlling whitespace here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#controlling-whitespace)